# How to install openjdk "1.8.0_20-b26" on amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, java

I'm pretty new to Linux and I need to install openjdk **1.8.0_20-b26** (that specific version) on a machine in AWS.
I'll appreciate if you could give some tips because it seems like using `yum` always install the latest one and trying to use `--showduplicates`yields nothing.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: unless you already have a copy of it, doesn't look like that specific version is available via the Oracle website downloads

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Open JDK**

Review the available JDK from your repo

```
$ yum --showduplicates list java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * extras: ftp.rezopole.net
 * updates: centos.quelquesmots.fr
Available Packages
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1.8.0.20-3.b26.el6            ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1.8.0.25-1.b17.el6            ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1.8.0.25-3.b17.el6_6          ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1:1.8.0.31-1.b13.el6_6        ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1:1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6       ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1:1.8.0.45-35.b13.el6         ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1:1.8.0.51-0.b16.el6_6        ol6_latest
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64        1:1.8.0.51-1.b16.el6_7        ol6_latest
....
```

and so download the specific version you need

for the JRE

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.20-3.b26.el6
```

including the JDK

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.20-3.b26.el6
```

**Oracle JDK**

This releases is also known as JDK 8u20 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html#R180_20)

> The full version string for this update release is 1.8.0_20-b26 (where "b" means "build"). The version number is 8u20..

you can download this specific version using

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

Comment: This downloads the regular Oracle JDK - not the **OpenJDK** version.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am trying to install it using Ansible modules as follows. However, you can refer to the package names mentioned below and try to install them manually.

**yum install java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto**

**yum install java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel**

```
- name: Install jdk and net-tools
  hosts: ip
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Update apt repo and cache
      dnf: update_cache=yes
    - name: Install jre and net-tools
      dnf:
        name:
          - java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto
          - java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel
          - net-tools
        state: present
```